# UI automator Viewer - Unable to select file in UI XML Dump

Tags: user-interface, viewer, uiautomatorviewer

I'm unable to maximixe UI Dump files alert in UI automator viewer and unable to see the 3 doted field in order to choose the dump file.

Please refer below for the issue image and help me on this. Thanks in Advance
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Lower the resolution of your monitor.

On Windows 10 you go:
Settings -> System -> Display

Scroll down to Display Resolution and lower it (mine worked on 1280 x 720).

When you reopen UIAutomator you should be able to Open UI Dump files.